# I've Created shop calculator in Python but it have some bugs

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

as u will se in my code i have 3 items in shop and want to show customer how much he bought
but the code is not working !!!
can any one fix it for me? I cant find the exact problem in it !!!
thank u so much

```
apple = 0.50
orange = 0.75
banana = 0.25
m = "f"
def calculator():
    m = input("Which fruit u want to purchase? \n press < a > for apple \n press < o > for orange \n press < b > for banana \n press e for exit: ")   
    a_p = 0
    o_p = 0
    b_p = 0
    total = a_p + o_p + b_p
    if m == "a":
          a_t = eval(input("How many ? "))
          a_p = apple * a_t
          total = a_p + total
          main()
    if m == "o":
           o_t = eval(input("How many ? "))
           o_p = orange * o_t
           total = total + o_p 
           main()
    if m == "b":
           b_t = eval(input("How many ? "))
           b_p = banana * b_t
           total = total + b_p
           main()
    else:
        total = str(total)
        print("You've purchased " + total + " dollar from our shop \n Have a nice day !!!")

def main():
    
        calculator();

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because nothing happens after you enter the amounts. See here from the first `if` block. You call `main()` but then you've got nothing following it to ever print because where you print your total is in an `else`.

```
if m == "a":
  a_t = eval(input("How many ? "))
  a_p = apple * a_t
  total = a_p + total
  main() # nothing happens after this, it cannot enter the `else` block
else:
    total = str(total)
    print("You've purchased " + total + " dollar from our shop \n Have a nice day !!!")
```

You're trying to do this recursively and although that can work you're probably better off with a `while` loop

Example for clarity:

```
total = 0
product = None
while product != "e":
    m = input("Which fruit u want to purchase? \n press < a > for apple \n press < o > for orange \n press < b > for banana \n press e for exit: ")
    number = eval(input("How many ? "))
    if m == "a":
        p = apple * number 
    elif m == "o":
        p = orange * number 
    total += p
    product = m # when this is "e" it will break the while loop
    
print("You've purchased " + total + " dollar from our shop \n Have a nice day !!!") # will print after the while loop has finished
```

Comment: thank u so much dude !!! wish u the bests